# multiple php upload with each file having a different target location

Tags: php, upload, targets

I am trying to create an upload on our site that basically we can add a variety of sized images to the input and they all go to there respective target locations.

Here is the form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select 120px image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="img120" id="img120">
    Select 125px image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="img125" id="img125">
    Select 600px image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="img600" id="img600">
    Select default image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="imgdef" id="imgdef">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Images" name="submit">
</form>
```

this submits to a php file called upload.php, the code of which is as follows:

```
// set upload target directory and filename

    $img120_dir = "../wp-content/uploads/ShortTermImages/120px/";
    $img120_file = $img120_dir . basename($_FILES["img120"]["name"]);

    $img125_dir = "../wp-content/uploads/ShortTermImages/125px/";
    $img125_file = $img125_dir . basename($_FILES["img125"]["name"]);

    $img600_dir = "../wp-content/uploads/ShortTermImages/600px/";
    $img600_file = $img600_dir . basename($_FILES["img600"]["name"]);

    $imgdef_dir = "../wp-content/uploads/ShortTermImages/";
    $imgdef_file = $imgdef_dir . basename($_FILES["imgdef"]["name"]);

// set file valid variable

    $img120_uploadOk = 1;
    $img125_uploadOk = 1;
    $img600_uploadOk = 1;
    $imgdef_uploadOk = 1;

// set file type

    $img120_FileType = pathinfo($img120_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $img125_FileType = pathinfo($img125_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $img600_FileType = pathinfo($img600_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $imgdef_FileType = pathinfo($imgdef_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// CHECK IF IMAGE IS AN ACTUAL IMAGE FILE   


    // Check 120px image      

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img120"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "<p style='color:#458B00'><strong>Success:</strong> File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".</p>";
            $img120_uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> File is not an image.";
            $img120_uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }


    // Check 125px image   

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img125"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "<p style='color:#458B00'><strong>Success:</strong> File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".</p>";
            $img125_uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> File is not an image.";
            $img125_uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }


    // Check 600px image      

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img600"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "<p style='color:#458B00'><strong>Success:</strong> File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".</p>";
            $img600_uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> File is not an image.";
            $img600_uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }


    // Check default image      

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["imgdef"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "<p style='color:#458B00'><strong>Success:</strong> File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".</p>";
            $img125_uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> File is not an image.";
            $img125_uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }


// CHECK IMAGE FILE SIZE    


    // Check 120px image      

        if ($_FILES["img120"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, your 120px file is too large.</p>";
            $img120_uploadOk = 0;
        }


    // Check 125px image      

        if ($_FILES["img125"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, your 125px file is too large.</p>";
            $img125_uploadOk = 0;
        }


    // Check 600px image      

        if ($_FILES["img600"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, your 600px file is too large.</p>";
            $img600_uploadOk = 0;
        }


    // Check default image      

        if ($_FILES["imgdef"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, your default image file is too large.</p>";
            $imgdef_uploadOk = 0;
        }


// ONLY ALLOW CERTAIN FILE FORMATS  


    // Check 120px image      

    if ( $img120_FileType != "jpg" && $img120_FileType != "png" 
        && $img120_FileType != "jpeg" && $img120_FileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, only <strong>JPG</strong>, <strong>JPEG</strong>, <strong>PNG</strong> &amp; <strong>GIF</strong> files are allowed.";
            $img120_uploadOk = 0;
    }


    // Check 125px image      

    if ( $img125_FileType != "jpg" && $img125_FileType != "png" 
        && $img125_FileType != "jpeg" && $img125_FileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, only <strong>JPG</strong>, <strong>JPEG</strong>, <strong>PNG</strong> &amp; <strong>GIF</strong> files are allowed.";
            $img125_uploadOk = 0;
    }


    // Check 600px image      

    if ( $img600_FileType != "jpg" && $img600_FileType != "png" 
        && $img600_FileType != "jpeg" && $img600_FileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, only <strong>JPG</strong>, <strong>JPEG</strong>, <strong>PNG</strong> &amp; <strong>GIF</strong> files are allowed.";
            $img600_uploadOk = 0;
    }


    // Check default image      

    if ( $imgdef_FileType != "jpg" && $imgdef_FileType != "png" 
        && $imgdef_FileType != "jpeg" && $imgdef_FileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'><strong>Error:</strong> Sorry, only <strong>JPG</strong>, <strong>JPEG</strong>, <strong>PNG</strong> &amp; <strong>GIF</strong> files are allowed.";
            $imgdef_uploadOk = 0;
    }


// CHECK IF UPLOAD IS VAILD AND UPLOAD


    // Check 120px image  

    if ($img120_uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "<h4>Your 120px file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</h4>";
    } else {

        // if file is vaild, try uploading file

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img120"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "<p style='color:#458B00;'><strong>SUCESS:</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["img120"]["name"]). " has been uploaded to ..../ShorttermImages/120px/</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'> Sorry, Your 120px file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</p>";
        }
    }


    // Check 125px image  

    if ($img125_uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "<h4>Your file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</h4>";
    } else {

        // if file is vaild, try uploading file

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img125"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "<p style='color:#458B00;'><strong>SUCESS:</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["img125"]["name"]). " has been uploaded to ..../ShorttermImages/125px/</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'> Sorry, Your 125px file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</p>";
        }
    }


    // Check 600px image  

    if ($img600_uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "<h4>Your file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</h4>";
    } else {

        // if file is vaild, try uploading file

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img600"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "<p style='color:#458B00;'><strong>SUCESS:</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["img600"]["name"]). " has been uploaded to ..../ShorttermImages/600px/</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'> Sorry, Your 600px file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</p>";
        }
    }


    // Check default image      

    if ($imgdef_uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "<h4>Your file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</h4>";
    } else {

        // if file is vaild, try uploading file

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgdef"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "<p style='color:#458B00;'><strong>SUCESS:</strong> The file ". basename( $_FILES["imgdef"]["name"]). " has been uploaded to ..../ShorttermImages/</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color:#dd0000;'> Sorry, Your default image file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.</p>";
        }
    }

?>
```

The script just will not function properly at the moment and i can't understand why?

orry The Output is the following:

```
Success: File is an image - image/jpeg. 
Success: File is an image - image/jpeg.     
Success: File is an image - image/jpeg. 
Success: File is an image - image/jpeg.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 192

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php2JSvCo' to '' in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 192 Sorry, Your 120px file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 208

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phplfhowF' to '' in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 208 Sorry, Your 125px file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 224

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpFv6hqW' to '' in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 224 Sorry, Your 600px file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 240

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpkpuhkd' to '' in /home/cocoonvehicles/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 240 Sorry, Your default image file was not uploaded, because there was an Error.
```

Comment: Can you tell us if you have an error or something ? Or is it secret ? And you should use loop to avoid duplication of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before going any further did you make sure you $target_file variable is populated. Looking through the code $target_file is never populated with anything. I threw in an arbitrary directory path and my images uploaded properly.

Comment: Thanks for the spot! I forgot to change all the $target_file variables to their relative ones. So they were $img120_file, $img125_file, $img600_file and $imgdef_file respectively!